# Is it possible to write each element of the unitary disk $\mathbb{D}={\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1}\}$ as $z=\text{tanh}(\frac{t}{2})e^{-i\theta}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization

Is it possible to write each element of the unitary disk $\mathbb{D}={\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1}\}$ as $z=\tanh(\frac{t}{2})e^{-i\theta}$ with $t>0$?

It seems simple, but I don't see how to verify it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That seems obvious: $t$ is the module of $z$ and $\theta$ its argument. However, if you want $t>$, you won't get $0$.

Comment: @J.rafa what is $\mathrm{tagh}(x)?$ Is it similar to a trigonometric function (e.g. is it periodic)?

Comment: @GerardWilliamson it's hyperbolic tangent

Comment: oh but you typed $\mathrm{tagh}(x)$ and not $\tanh(x)$ so that's why I was confused

Comment: @GerardWilliamson Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z \in \Bbb{D}$.  Then, in the [polar representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane), $z = r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \varphi}$, where $|z| = r$ and $\varphi = \arg(z)$ satisfy $0 \leq r < 1$.  (Typically, one also restricts $\varphi$ to some half-open interval with width $2\pi$, but we don't need to do so.)

The hyperbolic tangent function has $\tanh(0) = 0$, $\tanh'(x) > 0$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \tanh(x) = 1$.  Consequently, for each $r \in [0,1)$, there is a unique $t/2$ such that $\tanh(t/2) = r$.  Also, if we set $\theta = -\varphi$, we have $z = \tanh(t/2)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}$ with $t \geq 0$.

If we restrict $t > 0$, then there is no way to represent the point $0 \in \Bbb{D}$.  So on this point, the answer to your question is "no."

Comment: don't you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\tanh(x)=0$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\tanh(x)=1?$

Comment: @GerardWilliamson : I did.  Thanks!  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\tanh$ is an odd bijection from $\mathbf R$ onto $(-1,1)$. So you have to solve $\tanh\frac t2=|z|$.

It will be useful to remember that in inverse function $\operatorname{argtanh}$ can be expressed as a log.

Comment: @GerardWilliamson: argtanh was not at all a typo: the name never was arctanh, which would be meaningless (there's no related angle nor circle arc  in this function: I just used the old name of what now usuallly denoted $\operatorname{artanh}$; The arg (or ar) stands for ‘argument’.